# NullPointerException when using database object

Tags: android

I'm new to Android, and i've got some issues. 
It looks like it's saying DB.EmployeeOperations.open() is having an null object passed to it, but I'm not sure.
Where I missed a step?
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

**Logcat**:

```java
 *  06-10 16:10:52.605 17203-17203/com.androidtutorialpoint.employeemanagementsystem E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.androidtutorialpoint.employeemanagementsystem, PID: 17203
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.androidtutorialpoint.employeemanagementsystem/com.androidtutorialpoint.employeemanagementsystem.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.androidtutorialpoint.employeemanagementsystem.DB.EmployeeOperations.open()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3019)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3050)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2425)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5294)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.androidtutorialpoint.employeemanagementsystem.DB.EmployeeOperations.open()' on a null object reference
        at com.androidtutorialpoint.employeemanagementsystem.MainActivity.onResume(MainActivity.java:148)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1257)
        at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6076)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3008)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3050) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2425) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
```

**Java Code:**

```or-tag-here
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    private Button addEmployeeButton;
    private Button editEmployeeButton;
    private Button deleteEmployeeButton;
    private Button viewAllEmployeeButton;
    private EmployeeOperations employeeOps;
    private static final String EXTRA_EMP_ID = "com.androidtutorialpoint.empId";
    private static final String EXTRA_ADD_UPDATE = "com.androidtutorialpoint.add_update";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        addEmployeeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_add_employee);
        editEmployeeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_edit_employee);
        deleteEmployeeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_delete_employee);
        viewAllEmployeeButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_view_employees);



        addEmployeeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,AddUpdateEmployee.class);
                i.putExtra(EXTRA_ADD_UPDATE, "Add");
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
        editEmployeeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getEmpIdAndUpdateEmp();
            }
        });
        deleteEmployeeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getEmpIdAndRemoveEmp();
            }
        });
        viewAllEmployeeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ViewAllEmployees.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.employee_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.menu_item_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    public void getEmpIdAndUpdateEmp(){

        LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        View getEmpIdView = li.inflate(R.layout.dialog_get_emp_id, null);

        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        // set dialog_get_emp_id.xml to alertdialog builder
        alertDialogBuilder.setView(getEmpIdView);

        final EditText userInput = (EditText) getEmpIdView.findViewById(R.id.editTextDialogUserInput);

        // set dialog message
        alertDialogBuilder
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("OK",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                                // get user input and set it to result
                                // edit text
                                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,AddUpdateEmployee.class);
                                i.putExtra(EXTRA_ADD_UPDATE, "Update");
                                i.putExtra(EXTRA_EMP_ID, Long.parseLong(userInput.getText().toString()));
                                startActivity(i);
                            }
                        }).create()
                .show();

    }


    public void getEmpIdAndRemoveEmp(){

        LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        View getEmpIdView = li.inflate(R.layout.dialog_get_emp_id, null);

        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        // set dialog_get_emp_id.xml to alertdialog builder
        alertDialogBuilder.setView(getEmpIdView);

        final EditText userInput = (EditText) getEmpIdView.findViewById(R.id.editTextDialogUserInput);

        // set dialog message
        alertDialogBuilder
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("OK",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                        // get user input and set it to result
                        // edit text
                        employeeOps = new EmployeeOperations(MainActivity.this);
                        employeeOps.removeEmployee(employeeOps.getEmployee(Long.parseLong(userInput.getText().toString())));
                        Toast t = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Employee removed successfully!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        t.show();
                    }
                }).create()
                .show();

    }



    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        employeeOps.open();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        employeeOps.close();

    }
}
```

Comment: I believe `onPause` gets called when the dialog is open anyway, so you would have gotten a closed database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you're calling `employeeOps.open()` in `onResume()`, but `employeeOps` is not instantiated yet, it's value is still `null`.

Take a look at the [Activity lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle).

As you can see, when an `Activity` gets created two methods get called before `onResume()`: `onCreate()` and `onStart()`.

If you would like to call the `open()` method of `EmployeeOperations` in `onResume()`, you need to have an instance of it by then.

Call the following in `onCreate()`:

```
employeeOps = new EmployeeOperations(this);
```

Comment: Yeah. I've got it, that was the issue. Problem solved, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is a misunderstanding of the [Android lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html). Specifically, from that resource,

> Once the `onCreate()` finishes execution, the system calls the `onStart()` and `onResume()` methods in quick succession.

What this means for you is that `onResume()` triggers before you ever set `employeeOps` to a non-null value. You're only initializing it in response to a button press, but your Activity is only visible for a very short duration before `onResume` is triggered.